# Validator to check input string in HTML fomat in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

I need to render HTML and CSS as Flutter widgets in flutter app. I got the input from API. I would like to check first the input am i getting is in HTML Format or not.

Answer (score 0):

**This Function checks whether your input is in HTML Format or not.**

```
        bool isHTML(String str) {
          final RegExp htmlRegExp =
              RegExp('<[^>]*>', multiLine: true, caseSensitive: false);
          return htmlRegExp.hasMatch(str);
        }
```

**Example**

```
            String input =
                "<p>Flutter is an open source framework by Google for building beautiful, natively compiled, multi-platform applications from a single codebase.</p>";
            
            bool isInHTMLFormat = Validator.isHTML(input); // output true
```

Based on this we can show HTML Content with the help of [Flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)